# Redirect after post in angular

Tags: angular, post, angular6

Hi I am writting a post request from my site to external site. After successfull post, it should automatically redirect to the given url with parameters given as 2nd parameter showed in form of that site, but it just won't happen. I tried putting `responseType: "text"` as 3rd parameter, which resulted a html of page in response that i want to redirect to. How can I perform an actual redirect without text response?

My function looks like that:

```
sendRequest() {
    //url that I am posting to and it should redirect to, params are given HTTPParams
    this.http.post(this.url,this.params)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
         //apparently following line is not needed.
         this.router.navigateByUrl(this.url);
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Error", error, this.params);
          this.data = error;
            },
        () => {
          console.log("POST is completed");
        });

  }
```

Comment: Simply call sendRequest() and after that navigate

Comment: Why don't you simply use a normal form with action="post" with the URL? If you want to post your data to a server that will then display its own HTML to the user submitting, that sounds like a much more straightforward solution that first sending off an XHR request and then redirecting manually.

Comment: currently is it taking to any other page?

Comment: no, nothing happens, but in inspect > resolve i get the page I need as text

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. As fjc commented, i just had to use action="post" in html with url. Previously i tried that, but nothing happened. After hours of debugging i found out that `Formsmodule` is overriding/preventing submitting the form, so that way didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using "router.navigate" in this case as using it would mean that you want to navigate to a route defined internally in your app.

Please try this instead :

```
sendRequest() {
    //url that I am posting to and it should redirect to, params are given HTTPParams
    this.http.post(this.url,this.params)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
         //apparently following line is not needed.
         //this.router.navigateByUrl(this.url);
         window.location.href = this.url;
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Error", error, this.params);
          this.data = error;
            },
        () => {
          console.log("POST is completed");
        });

  }
```

It should redirect to the said url, leaving the angular app

Comment: It won't work. Nothing happens. Apparently it should automatically redirect to that page without being explicitly told.

Comment: I might suggest this then: "window.location.assign('http://external-url');" instead ".href" - if it works, I'll update the answer